# Javascript not functioning unless developer tools running

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I have the following button:

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset();" ID="btnReset" class="button textButton" style="bottom:8px; right:8px;" />
```

The reset function looks like this:

```
function reset() {
    try {
        alert('working');
        front = document.getElementById("hdnFrontBack").value === "true";
        if (!front) {
            front = true;
            myimage.src = myimage.src.substring(0, myimage.src.length - 4);
        }
        myimage.style.height = defHeight;
        if (myimage.naturalWidth != 0)
            currentZoom = defHeight / myimage.naturalHeight;
        document.getElementById("hdnFrontBack").value = front;
    }
    catch (exp) {
        alert(exp);
    }
}
```

This button does nothing when I first load the page.
In IE11 it will start working as soon as I launch developer tools (F12) and continue working after that even if I close developer tools.
In Chrome, it will only work as long as I have developer tools running.

Does anyone have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Try renaming `reset` to something else.

Comment: What are defheight and naturalHeight?

Comment: `onclick="window.reset();"` event attribs are executed with a context that essentially matches `var event=arguments[0]; with(this){ eval(strAttribValue);}` (another good reason to use addEventListener()...) since forms have a reset method, you're seeing the local reset method in lexical scope, not your global reset function.

Comment: @LeeTaylor make your comment an answer and I will accept it.  That not only fixed my issue but fixed another bug as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `reset` is a pre-existing function so the javascript engine is getting confused. Rename `reset` to something else and I believe your problem will disappear.